# Create xmlns attribute in the XML using XSLT Transformation

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I am trying to add the xmlns attribute to the resulting XML with a value passed by parameter  during XSLT transformation using JDK Transformer (Oracle XML v2 Parser or JAXP) but it always defaults to http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/

My source XML

```
<test/>
```

My XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://example.com">
    <xsl:param name="myNameSpace" select="'http://neilghosh.com'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <process>
            <xsl:attribute name="xmlns:neil">
                <xsl:value-of select="$myNameSpace"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </process>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Result

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<process xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/" xmlns:neil="neilghosh.com">
</process>
```

My Desired Result

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<process xmlns="http://example.com"  xmlns:neil="neilghosh.com">
</process>
```

Comment: You should use a valid URI for the namespace, e.g. `http://example.com/`, not `http://example.com`. Browsers will correct the latter to the former if you enter them into a location bar, but that's correcting an obvious mistake on input. You can't have an HTTP URI with no path part.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, in the XSLT data model, you don't want to create an attribute node, you want to create a namespace node.

Namespace nodes are usually created automatically: if you create an element or attribute in a particular namespace, the requisite namespace node (and hence, when serialized, the namespace declaration) are added automatically by the processor.

If you want to create a namespace node that isn't necessary (because it's not used in the name of any element or attribute) then in XSLT 2.0 you can use xsl:namespace. If you're stuck with XSLT 1.0 then there's a workaround, that involves creating an element in the relevant namespace and then copying its namespace node:

```
<xsl:variable name="ns">
  <xsl:element name="neil:dummy" namespace="{$param}"/>
</xsl:variable>
<process>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$ns/*/namespace::neil"/>
</process>
```

Comment: Does that work when the `$ns` variable holds a RTF rather than a node-set?  I'd have expected to need an `exslt:node-set()` call or similar to convert it first.

Comment: Thanks the following code under template did not work   <xsl:variable name="ns">
   <xsl:element name="neil:dummy" namespace="{$myNameSpace}"/>
  </xsl:variable>



  <process>
   <xsl:copy-of select="$ns/*/namespace::neil"/>
  </process>
 Can you edit your solution to the exact XSLT I need to write for this question ?

Comment: @NeilGhosh, Maybe you have heard about the `xxx:node-set()` extension function?

Comment: Yes, I think it needs xx:node-set(). Sorry, I only point people in the right direction, I don't take them by the hand and walk them there - especially when it involves XSLT 1.0 because that's always such an unpleasant journey.

Answer (score 5):

Michael Kay provided you with the correct answer, but based on your comments, you aren't sure how to use it in your transformation.

**Here is a complete transformation**:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pNamespace" select="'neilghosh.com'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDummy">
   <xsl:element name="neil:x" namespace="{$pNamespace}"/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:element name="process" namespace="http://example.com">
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="ext:node-set($vDummy)/*/namespace::*[.=$pNamespace]"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<test/>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<process xmlns="http://example.com" xmlns:neil="neilghosh.com" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am getting the following error  a.xsl<Line 11, Column 41>: XML-23049: (Error) FOTY0021: invalid node type

Comment: Is this because my JDeveloper's  oracle.xml.parser.v2.XSLProcessor ? Any better way to v2 parser ?

Comment: Removed the Oracle v2 parser library and got above code running but output was <ns0:process xmlns:ns0="http://example.com" xmlns:neil="neilghosh.com"/>

Comment: @NeilGhosh, I have run this with all 9 XSLT processor I am working with -- all produce the output I copied and pasted into this answer. Can you use MSXML, .NET XslCompiledTransform, Saxon, XQSharp or AltovaXML (XML-SPY)?

Comment: I am not sure if I can use above parses in my code . I ran the same code in NetBeans and it gave ns0 prefix as well unnecessarily

Comment: @NeilGhosh, This cannot be controlled. The W3 Spec allows it: "XSLT processors may make use of the prefix of the QName specified in the name attribute when selecting the prefix used for outputting the created element as XML; however, they are not required to do so."

Comment: thanks ! I have to use oracle.xml.parser.v2.XSLProcessor. Trying to find if XML-23049 error can be avoided.

Comment: Thanks, the solution worked for me. In my case I have used simply `<xsl:copy-of select="ext:node-set($vDummy)/*/namespace::*" />` without extra param `$pNamespace` voodo.

Comment: May I ask a question: how is it possible to copy namespaces from `<xsl:stylesheet>` element? E.g. how to use current stylesheet as node-set? Something like `current()/ancestor::xsl:stylesheet`, but I failed to make it working...

Comment: @dma_k: one selects the `document-node()` (/) of the current stylesheet module, using this XPath expression: `document('')`

Answer (score 2):

Namespace declarations in XML are not attributes even though they look like attributes.  In XSLT 2.0 you can use `<xsl:namespace name="neil" select="$myNameSpace" />` to add a namespace declaration to the result tree dynamically but that feature is not available in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: I added   <xsl:element name="process" namespace="{$myNameSpace}"> 
  <xsl:namespace name="neil" select="$myNameSpace" />
  </xsl:element>  under template but it still gives me output <process xmlns="http://neilghosh.com"/>

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to create "xmlns" attributes yourself. Create the namespaces in the XSLT and they will be done automatically.
This XSLT works (tested with Saxon 9.4):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:neil="neilghosh.com"    
xpath-default-namespace="http://example.com"
xmlns="http://example.com" version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="myDynamicNamespace" select="'http://neilghosh.com'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="process">   
        <xsl:namespace name="neil" select="$myDynamicNamespace"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And gives the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<process xmlns="http://example.com" xmlns:neil="http://neilghosh.com"/>
```

Comment: The whole point of the question is that the value of xmlns is supposed to come from the parameter [sent by  transformer.setParameter("myNameSpace", "http://example.com") ] "myNameSpace"

Comment: ok - so the element "process" should be in the namespace that comes from the parameter. I'll try to create an element inside of <process> that has the namespace from the parameter...

Comment: <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="process" namespace="{$myNameSpace}">
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: I need to have it in the root tag that is process

Comment: xsl:namespace didn't work even tough <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15977/discussion-between-neilghosh-and-fiveo)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got an workaround which worked with  my XSLT Processor (Oracle XML V2 Parser)

I had to [transform it to a DOM Document](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/TransforminganXMLFilewithXSLintoaDOMDocument.htm) and then persist that DOM to filesystem instead of outputting directly to [StreamResult](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamResult.html)

I used [DOMResult](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/dom/DOMResult.html) in the [transform method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#transform%28javax.xml.transform.Source,%20javax.xml.transform.Result%29)

Following XSLT fragment worked but there was an extra xmlns:xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/" which was probably absorbed by [Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) and did not appear in the final output when I persisted to file system.

```
 <process>    
      <xsl:attribute name="xmlns">
        <xsl:value-of select="'http://example.com'"/>
      </xsl:attribute> 
 <process>
```

I know this is not the best way to do but given the parse constraint this is the only choice I have now.