# XSLT to replace a namespace and also add a new (unused) namespace

Tags: xslt, namespaces

I want to replace the namespace of the following XML Document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<ns0:Document xmlns:ns0="http://mydata.com/H2H/Automation">    
  <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
    <GrpHdr>
    </GrpHdr>
  </CstmrCdtTrfInitn> 
</ns0:Document>
```

with the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    
  <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
    <GrpHdr>
    </GrpHdr>
  </CstmrCdtTrfInitn> 
</Document>
```

Any idea about XSLT which can convert this?

I have tried the following XSL, but it is adding the namespace with second Node and also not able to remove first namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <xsl:copy-of select="./*" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: No Idea how to write XSLT to remove old name and to add two new name spaces

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be a bit tricky: replacing the default namespace of the `Document` element is straightforward. But adding the unused `xslns:xsi` namespace in XSLT-1.0 requires the EXSLT extension and a special technique explained by Michael Kay in reply to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12179258/1305969). It involves creating an unused element in a global variable whose namespace is then copied in the template replacing the default namespace. In XSLT-2.0 and above this would be easier (see below).

*The EXSLT extension is not available in all XSLT-1.0 processors. But it is necessary to create a node-set from the variable.*

So all namespaces are to be defined in the `xsl:stylesheet` element, and then the root element (here `ns0:Document`) is matched by a template and replaced with its `local-name()` part with the new default namespace added, followed by copying the "dummy" namespace of the element defined in the variable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="http://mydata.com/H2H/Automation" xmlns:urn="urn:iso:std:iso"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    
    <!-- identity template (except elements)-->
    <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::*)]|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:variable name="nsXSI">
        <xsl:element name="xsi:dummy" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
    </xsl:variable>   
   
    <xsl:template match="ns0:*|*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="urn:iso:std:iso">
            <xsl:copy-of select="ext:node-set($nsXSI)/*/namespace::xsi" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output should be as expected, even in XSLT-1.0:

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
      <GrpHdr>
      </GrpHdr>
   </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

---

The simplified solution requires an XSLT-2.0 capable processor. Then you can use the [xsl:namespace](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/xsl-elements/namespace.html) instruction as follows and don't need the "dummy" variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="http://mydata.com/H2H/Automation">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- identity template (except elements)-->
    <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::element())]|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  
   
    <xsl:template match="ns0:*|*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}" namespace="urn:iso:std:iso">
            <xsl:namespace name="xsi">http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance</xsl:namespace>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is the same.

---

The above XSLT-2.0 solution could be further simplified by using XSLT-3.0+'s `xsl:mode` to replace the *identity template* with

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. It is giving me error sapximapping:nsfinal.xsl: line 6: Error parsing XPath expression 'node()[not(self::element())]|@*'

Comment: You were right. I had to add an external library named EXSLT to make the XSLT-1.0 answer work and changed the `element()` to `*`.

Comment: Sorry didn't get, should I change anything in above solution.

Comment: Yes. I changed the XSLT. You also need the EXSLT extension to use the XSLT-1.0 solution. If you do not have it available, you'd be stuck with XSLT-2.0 or above.

Comment: Thanks modified version worked to some extent but it has added  urn:iso:std:iso with all parent nodes ns1 ns2 ns3

Comment: <ns289:Document xmlns:ns289="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ns290:CstmrCdtTrfInitn xmlns:ns290="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">

Comment: Of course, this answer does neither include `ns289:*` nor `ns290:*` and so on. I guess that your MCVE was incomplete...

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you cannot do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://mydata.com/H2H/Automation"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="urn:iso:std:iso">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/ns0:Document">
    <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Document>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```