# XSLT: Unexpected inherited null xmlns attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am writing a transformation where I would like to add a xmlns attribute (`xmlns="myNS"`) to the root node.

When applying the transformation the `xmlns` attribute is included in some of the child elements.

I can't work out how to change my transformation to only apply it to the root element.

**XML**

```
<db:result xmlns:db="http://www.sonicsw.com/esb/service/dbservice">
    <db:resultSet version="1.1">
        <db:row>
            <id>a</id>
            <value1>b</value1>
            <value2>c</value2>
        </db:row>
        <db:row>
            <id>a</id>
            <value1>d</value1>
            <value2>e</value2>
        </db:row>
        <db:row>
            <id>a</id>
            <value1>f</value1>
            <value2>g</value2>
        </db:row>
        <db:row>
            <id>a</id>
            <value1>h</value1>
            <value2>i</value2>
        </db:row>
    </db:resultSet>
</db:result>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:db="http://www.sonicsw.com/esb/service/dbservice" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="db">
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="//db:row" group-by="id">
                <xsl:sort select="id"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="document"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="db:row" mode="document">
        <root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="myNS">
            <id><xsl:value-of select="id"/></id>
            <lines>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//db:row[id=current()/id]" mode="line"/>
            </lines>
        </root>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="db:row" mode="line">
        <line>
            <valueof1><xsl:value-of select="value1"/></valueof1>
            <valueof2><xsl:value-of select="value2"/></valueof2>
        </line>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="myNS">
    <id>a</id>
    <lines>
        <line xmlns="">
            <valueof1>b</valueof1>
            <valueof2>c</valueof2>
        </line>
        <line xmlns="">
            <valueof1>d</valueof1>
            <valueof2>e</valueof2>
        </line>
        <line xmlns="">
            <valueof1>f</valueof1>
            <valueof2>g</valueof2>
        </line>
        <line xmlns="">
            <valueof1>h</valueof1>
            <valueof2>i</valueof2>
        </line>
    </lines>
</root>
```

**XML Expected Output**

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="myNS">
    <id>a</id>
    <lines>
        <line>
            <valueof1>b</valueof1>
            <valueof2>c</valueof2>
        </line>
        <line>
            <valueof1>d</valueof1>
            <valueof2>e</valueof2>
        </line>
        <line>
            <valueof1>f</valueof1>
            <valueof2>g</valueof2>
        </line>
        <line>
            <valueof1>h</valueof1>
            <valueof2>i</valueof2>
        </line>
    </lines>
</root>
```

*Note: I found this existing post but can't workout how to apply the suggested solution:*

- [Problem with adding xmlns attribute to XML document using XSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490246/problem-with-adding-xmlns-attribute-to-xml-document-using-xsl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literal result elements in a stylesheet take their namespace from the `xmlns` declarations in scope at that point *in the stylesheet*, i.e. within

```
    <root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="myNS">
        <id><xsl:value-of select="id"/></id>
        <lines>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//db:row[id=current()/id]" mode="line"/>
        </lines>
    </root>
```

the `root` element and all its unprefixed children are in the `myNS` namespace.  However in

```
<xsl:template match="db:row" mode="line">
    <line>
        <valueof1><xsl:value-of select="value1"/></valueof1>
        <valueof2><xsl:value-of select="value2"/></valueof2>
    </line>
</xsl:template>
```

the `line` and `valueofN` elements are in no namespace, since there's no default `xmlns` in scope at this point in the stylesheet.

So the simple answer is to move the `xmlns="myNS"` from the `root` element in the `db:row` template up into the top-level `xsl:stylesheet` instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns="myNS"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:db="http://www.sonicsw.com/esb/service/dbservice" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="db">
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="//db:row" group-by="id">
                <xsl:sort select="id"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="document"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="db:row" mode="document">
        <root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <id><xsl:value-of select="id"/></id>
            <lines>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//db:row[id=current()/id]" mode="line"/>
            </lines>
        </root>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="db:row" mode="line">
        <line>
            <valueof1><xsl:value-of select="value1"/></valueof1>
            <valueof2><xsl:value-of select="value2"/></valueof2>
        </line>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Though note that this stylesheet will not produce well-formed output if the `row` elements in the original XML don't all have the same id, as you'll get multiple `root` elements with no single parent.  You may wish to add a wrapping element in the `match="/"` template to ensure the output is well formed.

P.S. since you're in a `for-each-group` it may be more efficient to lose the `mode="document"` template and move its content directly inside the f-e-g, then use `current-group` instead of having to filter for `[id=current()/id]`:

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//db:row" group-by="id">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            <root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <id><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></id>
                <lines>
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="line"/>
                </lines>
            </root>        
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
```